# Atalho ctrl+/ no vscode

Tags: json, visual-studio-code

Estou tentando colocar o atalho ctrl + / para comentar linhas no vscode, porém estou com dificuldade em deixar o atalho complementar, ou seja, fazer com que o atalho ctrl + / adicione comentários e também faça o trabalho de remoção de comentários.

Aqui está parte do trecho do meu código de configuração keybindings.json:

Onde ctrl+abnt_c1 seria o atalho ctrl + /

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+abnt_c1",
        "command": "editor.action.addCommentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+abnt_c1",
        "command": "editor.action.removeCommentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Olá Acredito que você esteja editando o atalhado errado. No meu caso uso `ctrl + ;`.

Adicionar Comentário:  **Fold All Block Comments** `editor.foldAllBlockComments`

Remover Comentários: **Toggle Line Comment** `editor.action.commentLine`

Você pode ir na Opção de **Keyboard Shortcuts** e buscar por **comment** e atribuir o atalho.

Comment: Ae vlw, agora está funcionando do jeito que eu queria. Abs.

Answer (score 0):

Tópico solucionado, agradeço bastante pela ajuda Ivan Antunes.

Meu código de configuração keybindings.json ficou assim agora:

```
    {
        "key": "ctrl+abnt_c1",
        "command": "editor.foldAllBlockComments",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
    {
        "key": "ctrl+abnt_c1",
        "command": "editor.action.commentLine",
        "when": "editorTextFocus && !editorReadonly"
    },
```

Comment: Que bom que conseguiu resolver o problema :)